# How do I force Windows 7 to play only through headphones?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, skype, speakers

Okay to make things clear; I'm going to give a step by step of what happened.

I've got a brand new laptop, and while installing stuff everything was fine. When I'd plug in headphones in the 3.5mm jack, all the sound would just go there instead of at my speakers, which is exactly as I want it.
Then I called someone on skype, and my laptop decided that it'd play all the sound over it's own speakers, even if headphones were pluuged in. Though I can fix skype by changing skype's audio options(to play over 3.5mm jack), when I call someone, the rest of my sound still goed over the internal speakers.

I want all the sound to go through my headphones whenever they're plugged in, no matter what I do. What should I do?

Comment: Try using the "Find and fix audio playback problems" troubleshooter. Search for `audio` in the control panel and it should be listed under Troubleshooting.

Comment: @Brian total loss of time, these troubleshooters won't do any good.

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming you haven't done this:

Go into your `Sound` settings from the `Control Panel` and set your head phones as the default device.

Are you on the screen below? A green tick should appear on the default device.

[image: Sound Settings]

Comment: I can change my headphones to 'default communication device' but not to 'default device'. The speakers are the 'default device' and it looks like I can't change that. I can only make the speakers the normal and communication default, but not neither. I can click on the 'set default' at my headphones, but it wont change.

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. Are you using earphones or a proper set of headphones?

Comment: I'm sure I'm in the right window. Internal speakers are default device. headphones are default communication device. I can click on make this the default device at the earphones, but it doesn't change anything. I'm using mobile phone earphones. one 3.5mm jack, extra contact for microphone which can't be used in laptop.

Comment: It's not that I haven't done that.. It's that I can't.

Comment: What about if you right-click on the headphones and choose Set as Default Device? I'm guessing that won't make a difference either.

Comment: no diffrence at all, can click it like it's an available option, but nothing happens.

Comment: Is it only Skype that's causing this? You could try the Sound settings in Skype. Tools - Options - Sound Settings.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yB4NBZK.png

Comment: It's calling with skype that creates this problem, I'm currently calling, so the rest of my sound is on the speakers. If I stop the call all the sound will go to my headphones again. So it has to do with skype, but I think that explains the 'default communication device'

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JNCW3HE.png?1

Comment: Try swapping the default communication device with the default device.

Comment: I got it to work. I made the speakers both the defaults and disabled it, this way it did swap to headphones.. (when the earphones where communication audio, it wouldn't) a bit of a hassle every time, but doable. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: This is the answer and I can't possibly write a better answer. Just set the headphones as the default device.

Comment: Like @DawnValentine , I could not set my headphones as Default. I right-clicked headphones, choose "Set as Default", nothing changed -- the green checkmark remains on the laptop speakers themselves.  I had to **disable the laptop speakers** -- I think that's the same as Dawn...

Answer (score 10):

The problem: There are two different 'default' devices. One for communications (Skype, Teamspeak, etc.) and one for everything else (e.g. games).

[image: problem]

The solution: Unplug the headphones, and **set the speakers as** both the 'default device' and **the 'default communications device'**.

[image: solution]

Now it should look like this:

[image: result]

Everything will play through the speakers. Plug the headphones back in. Everything will play through the headphones (even though speakers are still selected as default). This is another example of silly windoge logic. Some programs will change the 'default communications device' back to the headset on startup (Teamspeak did this to me).

Comment: Can't believe this worked - cheers

Comment: To make it work when Realtek Audio Manager installed I had to open Realtek, open `Device advanced settings` and then choose `Mute the rear output device, when a front headphone plugged in`.

Comment: BornToCode, thank you for that comment. I don't have a realtek device but I discovered that the auto-switching functionality can be turned off in my own soundcard settings, separate from windows.

Comment: That worked for me!! I can't believe it. Thanks @rudolfbyker.
Windows plays with our mind. Send a hello form me to Bill Gates.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing that seemed to work was:

Control Panel >Manage Audio Devices

There should be 4 options; Playback, Recording, Sounds, and Communications. If you click on Recording look to see if there's an Internal Mic option in the list. If so, click on it then click properties. Another window will open up and from there click the Listen tab. If Listen to this Device is checked, uncheck it and click Apply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem where my computer would show "speakers and headphones" as default device, and then a separate "communications headphones" category too. I am using iPod headphones with the microphone, so when I plugged in the headphones, they would go to the communications category.

What fixed it was when I disabled "communications headphones," then it would register my headphones as normal and work.

Comment: This is the correct answer; some PCs expose two independent sound devices, a speakers/headphones one and an "independent headphones" (or similar); disable the independent one and everything should work just fine (reconfigure your apps to use the "speakers/headphones" device).

Comment: I've been struggling with a similar issue for months, and this is the only thing that helped me. My problem was anytime I had an alert pop up or I switched folders in the file explorer, it would momentarily re-route sound through the main speakers. This solution seems counter-intuitive, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me: unplugging my headphones, setting the speakers as the default and default communications device and then disabling the communication headphones bullish seemed to make all the sound play in the headphones when i use them.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem by uninstalling the audio drivers my computer came with and using generic audio drivers instead.

In my case:

- Audio driver (problematic): `IDT Audio`
- Playback device title: `Communication Headphones`
- Audio driver (working): `High Definition Audio Device`

Uninstalling `IDT Audio` via the device manager resulted in `IDT Audio` automatically re-installing itself. After some experimentation I discovered a way to finally remove it:

1. Go to `Control Panel` > `Sound` > `Playback`
2. Right-click the playback device you want and select `Properties`
3. Locate the `Controller information` section under the `General` tab and click the `Properties` button
4. Navigate to `Driver` tab and click the `Update Driver` button
5. Choose `Browse my computer for driver software`
6. Click `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`
7. Make sure `Show compatible hardware` is checked
8. If options are available - continue to install them one-by-one until you've tried everything.

Following those steps fixed my sound problems immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The way I fixed it was to open the sound tab by right clicking the speaker icon, click the headphones, and go to properties. Select advanced and uncheck the `allow applications to take exclusive control of this device`. Click OK. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty specific, but may help someone trying to figure this out.  I was having the same issue, probably after installing skype, and on my laptop (HP Elitebook) I couldn't set the default device to "communication Headphones" through the windows interface, but was able to do it through the "Catalyst Control Center" (by right clicking and selecting it as default device).  Now everything works as it did out of the box, playing through the speakers normally, and through headphones when they're connected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I fixed it by disabling and re-enabling the headphone under Sounds -> Playback.,

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've figured out the answer. I had the same issue and it was an interesting fix. See if this works for you.

1. I right-clicked on the speaker icon in the Windows Start Bar and pressed **Playback Devices**.
2. Right-click on the device that represents your 3.5mm headphone jack and select **Properties**.
3. Go to the **Enhancements** tab.
4. I found that no enhancements were enabled. I checked all the enhancement boxes (i.e. Bass Boost, Loudness Equalization).
5. I had Pandora Internet Radio playing while I did this and it was playing from the laptop speakers only, even though the 3.5mm plug was plugged in (I was using it for speakers, not headphones). I hit the **Apply** button and the music immediately went to the external speakers).

Answer (score 0):

Look! if you have the problem with headphones, this answer will help you. 
After Searching and many attempting,  it worked.

I would suggest you to check with  volume settings and check if it helps.

1. Right click on the speaker icon in taskbar and select volume control options.
2. put a check mark on "All devices currently playing sound".
3. Make sure you have "The default communication device unchecked".
4. Place a check mark on both speakers and headphones.

Yet, if it has been not changed, this is key.
You have to plug a hand free(headphones) on its place and try these steps again. Eventually, It will work.
Those steps based on my actual experiment.

Comment: When you say ‘‘Look!’’, you sound like you’re angry, or you’re making some big announcement.  When you say ‘‘this will help you’’, you sound like a salesman. Try to sound more like a teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the sound icon on the notification area of the task bar then click Playback devices then right click speakers and disable it then do the same for the headphones then what you do is to re-enable the headphones first then the speakers then click ok.

P.S. it worked for me and even worked when i tried sound on discord afterwards

Answer (score -1):

Right-click the speaker icon in the notification area (it should have a red X on it)
Choose "Playback devices"
The Sound control panel should appear, on the "Playback Devices" tab - there won't be any playback devices visible.
Right-click in the main area of the window where the devices would normally appear.
Check the "Show Disabled Devices" option.

At this point your speakers should re-appear, but will still be disabled.
Right-click the speakers and choose Enable

Comment: The question says nothing about the speakers disappearing. Where did you get that idea from?